# I keep getting errors when getting image with gatsby-image and graphql

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am trying to add an image sourced from graphql. I've run into this problem a few times now and always end up lucking out into a fix.

When querying the image I get this response:

> The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL.
>   Received type undefined

The code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, graphql, useStaticQuery, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'
import './longCard.css';

const CardData = props => {

    const slug = props.slug;
    return (
        <StaticQuery
            query={
                graphql`
            query($slug: String) {
                sanityProduct(slug: {current: {eq: $slug}}) {
                    slug{ 
                        current
                    }
                    title
                    featured_image {
                        asset {
                            childImageSharp {
                                fixed {
                                    ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
`}
            render={data => <LongCard />}
        />
    )
}

export default CardData

export const LongCard = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <div className="long-card">
            <div className="long-card-inner">
                <Link to={data.sanityProduct.slug.current}>{data.sanityProduct.title}</Link>
                {/* Add image */}
                <Img fixed={data.featured_image.asset.childImageSharp.fixed} />
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't need the ChildImageSharp section, I think this is only for querying the file-system.